# Route all traffic through OpenVPN hosted on EC2

Tags: openvpn

I need to setup our openvpn server to allow all traffic togo through it when we connect(as we need to whitelist its public IP address).
The problem I'm having is that once I start to route all traffic through vpn I lose all connectivity. Here's my config:

```
server 172.16.253.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /tmp/ipp.txt

push "route 172.16.64.0 255.255.224.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.16.64.2"
```

`172.16.64.2` is VPC dns server ip address. 
When I connect to vpn and try traceroute 8.8.8.8 I get the following:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  ip-172-16-253-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal (172.16.253.1)  30.283 ms  15.633 ms  16.482 ms
 2  * * *
```

This is where it stops. My route tables point `172.16.253.0/24` to the EC2 instance hosting openVPN. Why is it not working and what am I missing?
Source/Dest check is disabled.

Comment: I think you have to enable forwarding on the server

Comment: @davidbaumann yes, I already figured this one out(with this command- iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s IP ADDRESS -o INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE). I NAT the traffic to the internet. My next problem is security group which does not allow this to work. Do you know perhaps which address and port I need to allow to make natting work?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. I had to change interface as in aws eth0 etc are not available. 
In my case it was ens5